# Merging two dataframes that share a date column

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say i have two dataframes (df_aapl) and (df_csco) and i wanna merge them based on the date(They both span the same timeframe and share the same dates).

I've tried pd.merge function but it duplicates the other columns. Like this...

(These are made up numbers)

| Date | Symbol_x | Price_x | Symbol_y | Price_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-12-23 | AAPL | 100 | CSCO | 20 |
| 2016-12-24 | AAPL | 120 | CSCO | 40 |
| 2016-12-25 | AAPL | 130 | CSCO | 50 |
| 2016-12-26 | AAPL | 140 | CSCO | 60 |

I want to merge them to look like this

[Example of Dataframe desired]

[image: 1]

Comment: Seems like you may want to `join` or `concat` instead of `merge` and then `groupby` your date and ticker columns

Comment: Will you please provide samples of your input dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df_aapl = pd.read_excel(r"Desktop\book2.xlsx",sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
df_csco = pd.read_excel(r"Desktop\book2.xlsx",sheet_name = 'Sheet2')

## Assuming both df_aapl,df_csco data frames have same number of columns with same names.
data = pd.concat([df_aapl,df_csco],axis=0)

data.head(10)

    Date       Symbol   Price
0   2016-12-23  AAPL    100
1   2016-12-23  AAPL    120
2   2016-12-23  AAPL    130
3   2016-12-23  AAPL    140
0   2016-12-23  CSCO    20
1   2016-12-23  CSCO    40
2   2016-12-23  CSCO    50
3   2016-12-23  CSCO    60

## Assuming sum of price of each symbol needed by date. This can be changed as per requirement

data.groupby(['Date','Symbol'])['Price'].sum().reset_index()

    Date       Symbol   Price
0   2016-12-23  AAPL    490
1   2016-12-23  CSCO    170
```